# Origin of "on the QT"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I was watching the movie L.A. Confidential last night, and was reminded of the phrase "on the QT", which Danny DeVito's character says several times.

> Off the record, on the QT, and very hush-hush...

I was wondering if anyone can shed any light on the origin and meaning of this phrase.

Comment: I've heard of "on the DL" for down-low, but not QT.

Comment: @Seth - QT is a hell of a lot older than DL...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently Q.T. is [derived from *quiet*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-the-qt.html) and originated in the 19th century, although its provenance is not certain.

From phrases.org.uk:

> The slang term 'qt' is a shortened form of 'quiet'. There's no definitive source for the phrase 'on the q.t.', although it appears to be of 19th century British origin - not, as is often supposed, American. The longer phrase 'on the quiet' is also not especially old, but is first recorded somewhat before 'on the qt', in Otago: Goldfields & Resources, 1862:

Comment: This is also what the NOAD reports.

Answer (score 13):

I found an earlier (1874) appearance of *Q.T.* that shows its origin is most likely from the British side of the pond. This clip appears in an American publication of short plays, but this particular farce, *My Husband's Secret* by Walter Devereux Whitty, Esq., shows on its title page (scroll up four pages) that it played first in London.
 Here's the [clip](http://books.google.com/books?id=8YtYAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=q.t.&f=false):

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=8YtYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA30-IA27&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U2SFG975KYWR8jC5_saZwK1lyp8oA&ci=28%2C134%2C444%2C216&edge=0]

A note on the date: Google Books lists this publication's date as 1876. The play's title page has its copyright date as 1873. I cross-checked the date of the play at [Open Library](http://openlibrary.org/books/OL13830821M/My_husband%27s_secret), where it has 1874.

**Edit:** Found an antedating of *on the quiet*, mentioned in @Robusto's answer, from a horseracing story in *[New Sporting Magazine](http://books.google.com/books?id=O4QEAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=%22on%20the%20quiet%22&f=false)*, 1847:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=O4QEAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=snippet&q=%22on%20the%20quiet%22&f=false]

Answer (score 9):

"Q.T." is an odd abbreviation for "quiet."  Since it is of British origin, I would think it would derive from schoolboys' abbreviations, often derived from Latin.   The Latin *taceo* means "not to speak" and has solemn meaning sometimes, referring to "passing over in silence."  Thus quae tacenda, or q.t., would refer to "things about which one should not speak."  Cf. Horace, Epodes, 5.49, where Horace speaks of Canidia and quid dixit et quid tacuit, what she said and what she left unsaid.

**Edit:** That in "My Husband's Secret" Straps says that "Q.T." is an abbreviation for "quiet," as one "should have larned at Hoxford," is a pretty good indication that Q.T. for "quiet" is a false etymology.  At Oxford and elsewhere schoolboys' lessons in the classics would have occasional obscene expressions.  I can imagine a teacher explicating a classical text, and then coming to the obscene part, and stating that "here there are quaedam tacenda [certain things about which one should keep silent]."  These would be frequent enough that schoolboys' notes would refer to these as q.t.  Then the term would be brought into ordinary conversation, e.g., referring to a master—"he drinks too much, and there are q.t. [i.e., he chases underage boys]."  Then the term would be used for schoolboys' pranks:  "I'll join you on this, but only on the strict q.t.," i.e., we won't brag about this even to our fellows.

All this just a guess, but I think a good one.

Comment: It's often written as _qt_, as opposed to Q.T. (although I've seen _qt, QT, q.t._, and Q.T._). As a footnote, I first stumbled on this phrase decades ago, when it was included in an early edition of an Official Scrabble Dictionary, where it raised many eyebrows as an easy (though surprising) way to use a Q. The word has since been deemed illegal; I found a short reference to the debate on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AList_of_English_words_containing_Q_not_followed_by_U#The_end_of_qt).

Answer (score 3):

### Oxford English Dictionary

The OED says it comes from the first and last letters of quiet, and is chiefly used as *on the (strict) q.t.*.

Their first quotation is:

> 1885   G. Moore Mummer's Wife ix. 126   It will be possible to have one spree on the strict q.t.

---

### Victorian music

I found an antedating.

[The University of Reading's Spellman Collection of Victorian Music Covers](http://www.vads.ac.uk/large.php?uid=63472) lists a song called *You should see us on the strict "Q.T."* from 1877 illustrated by Alfred Bryan, composed by Walter Redmond and written by Geoffrey Thorn.

[image: You should see us on the strict "Q.T."]

The description is:

> Caricature portrait, full length, of G H Macdermott; the titles of some of his songs around his feet.

And it includes the text:

> (Chorus) Oh my! what a pious world this is
> And how very good we all seem to be
> What a duffing lot you find
> If you only raise the blind
> And see us on the strict "Q T."

---

### The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins

[The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-the-qt.html) says:

> As to on the q.t., in *The Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins*, Robert Hendrickson states:
>
> > "A British broadside ballad (1870) contained the line 'Whatever I tell you is on the Q.T.'"
>
> It would be good to know the name of the ballad in order to follow up this assertion. Unfortunately, the author doesn't give it, from which we can only suppose he didn't know it himself. Without some supporting evidence that claim has to be in doubt.

Answer (score 2):

According to [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/on-the-qt.html), the origin, while somewhat uncertain, is most likely 19th-century British.

[Daily Writing Tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/on-the-qt/), on the other hand, puts forth some argument for the US origin since the phrase is documented to have appeared in print in 1884, and was in a song in 1879.

[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-ont2.htm) cites the use of "QT" as an abbreviation as a clear sign that the origin must have been US, based on abbreviationism being a known linguistic feature of late 19th-century American English.

All three are clear that the QT is short for "quiet" and the phrase means "confidential" or "off the record".