# What is a word that describes a secret that passes on from a person to person?

Tags: meaning, etymology, american-english

I forgot this word. I tell a person a secret and ask him not to tell it to anyone else. That 2nd person tells another person and tells him not to disclose it to anyone else. But this goes on.

Important thing here is that, the info should be kept secret. But he assumes he is only disclosing this to another person (may be a close friend or spouse) and that that info will not go out. But the other person assumes the same and passes on to his close friend or spouse or someone s/he most trusts, etc..

Note that, the info passes from one person to another person. Not group or mass public.

Comment: A 'rumour' perhaps? 'Gossip'?

Comment: a "non-secret"...

Comment: Gossip is a good answer here, for many reasons. There was a game we played as kids called *telephone*, but it wasn't intended to be a secret.

Comment: Are you looking for [_grapevine_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapevine_%28gossip%29)?

Comment: This sounds like Chinese Whispers, "also known as broken telephone, operator, grapevine, gossip, don't drink the milk, secret message, the messenger game and pass the message." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers

Comment: Also sounds like "confidential", "web of lies", or "rumor/gossip mill"... but I'm not sure what, specifically, you are asking. Is it the the person sharing the secret, the nature of the message (that it should be kept secret), or the behavior of the people who are being told the secret?

Comment: There also might not be an English word to describe this. http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2151359

Comment: Perhaps huggermugger or sub rosa?

Comment: I give up researching for a word... If it isn't on this list I have to conclude this isn't a word - or at least one that is widely used. http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/telling+a+secret

Answer (score 1):

> One technical phrase for it would be ["single-strand chain"](http://www.uta.edu/faculty/mputnam/COMS309/Notes/FormalandInformal.html)---I tell you a rumor and then you pass it along to another person, who then tells another, and on-and-on....

"single-strand-chains" are a kind of Grapevine Transmission Pattern" or "Informal Communication Network", a strategy sometimes used in the corporative world.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be referring to "open secret" i.e. a "secret" that isn't a secret at all because everyone knows about it?

Comment: Nope. It goes from one person to another person, not in mass. Each person telling other person not to disclose to anyone. There is word I read almost a decade ago, which I can't recall now.

Comment: ok. Not sure I've ever heard of a single word that describes a confidence that is broken is such a specific way... Whispernet?

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Don't understand downvote. Suggestion was not the correct answer sought by OP, but that doesn't invalidate it as a suggestion in the absence of a clear answer? @Kristina, the fact it was posted as an answer should give you a clue. What is your point?

Comment: Marv, I'm not the downvoter, for starters, but my point is that an answer is not a question.  It's an answer with hopefully, some cited source to back it up.  What you posted as an answer is usually a comment to the OP to get more clarification so an answer can be given.

Comment: I must disagree- the OP asked for some information. In my opinion they are probably mistaken and there is no such one-word answer to describe their meaning.  I asked them if what they were seeking was my suggestion- rather than answering a question with a question, it is merely a colloquial way of suggesting an answer. I would have thought that was obvious, though clearly not to everyone.

Comment: Please don't phrase answers as questions. Answers should be answers. It's ok to start with "You may be referring to..." if you believe there is some uncertainty.

Comment: Sorry for the edit. I was just trying to get people off your back. This is a perfectly reasonable answer, even if it's not exactly what the OP wants. +1 from me. Anyway, sorry for interfering. I thought a rollback would remove my avatar. :(

Comment: @MarvMills - yes, that's what I did. I thought it would be a help, but then thought maybe not. I'm commenting on your question in meta and should be finished soon.

Answer (score 0):

In common with others who answered or commented, I can't think of a single word that answers your question, but the phrase **on the QT** seems pretty close.

From [dictionary.com:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on+the+qt)

> q.t.
>
> abbreviation (informal)
>
> 1. quiet
> 2. on the q.t., secretly

And from the same entry, quoting *The Dictionary of American Slang:*

> on the QT
>
> **adjective phrase**
>
> *: Remember, what I said is on the QT*

There is a detailed discussion of **on the QT** in [this answer.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12651/origin-of-on-the-qt)

Comment: Also on the DL works too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down-low